# how to create cookie less sub domain on mobile site.

Tags: cookies, cookieless

I run my mobile website in m.example.com and I created another sub domain for serving static content that is static.example.com.

But static.example.com serving the cookies data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Cookie-less only works with a specific path.  In your case the path needs to be m.example.com not .example.com.  Can you share the path of the cookies you are seeing sent to your static.example.com subdomain?

Comment: In Mozilla firebug it showing / as path

Comment: Sorry, I meant domain not path.  If the domain shows .example.com then it is applying that cookie to all subdomains of example.com.

Comment: my implementation has made cookie less my all images but when i update  src attribute of any Image tag using Jquery attr() function then image    load with cookies data. How to remove these cookies for these late image loading request.

Comment: is it possible that something is setting browser session-cookies at the .example.com domain during the loading of the page?  If the images are at the same domain as the others they should exhibit the same behavior as it will only send along cookies that match the domain.